# in telegram, get text of an alert once it gets displayed

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

i need to get the text displayed as a alert in telegram.

When i receive a message sent with hide it bot i need to press the button "Read" to see the message which is displayed as an alert, so i need to get that text.

Here it's a part of my code that finish pressing the button "Read" but i don't know how to continue.

the alert is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGRHX.png

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='Hola123'))
async def handler(event):
        buttons = await event.get_buttons()
        for bline in buttons:
            for button in bline:
                print(button.button.text)
                if 'Read' in button.button.text:
                    print('Pressing button')              
                    await button.click()

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: maybe `await button.click()` will return the details

Comment: @MalikTahir is right, just read what `await button.click()` returns, it should contain a `message` parameter!

Comment: @MalikTahir you are right, thanks for helping me guys!

Comment: It sounds like @MalikTahir had this fixed. This could probably be added as an answer.